# Create date column based on range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of dates.

```
   colA      
1  12 may
2  3 sep
3  4 aug
```

How could I create date_col? The dates must be between 01/04/2021 and 31/03/2022

```
   colA        date_col
1  12 may     12/05/2021
2  3 sep      03/09/2021
3  4 mar      04/03/2022
```